# Implementing Stories feature in Android

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement something similar to the Stories feature in Facebook or WhatsApp.

**Possible approaches** :

1. At first, I wanted to open a web socket so I could receive the latest Stories updates (new story from a friend, or if a story was removed).
2. There'a another alternative - getting those updates using FCM pushes.
   A service which receives the pushes broadcasts the "new story"/"story removed" broadcast using a LocalBroadcastManager, and the suitable activity which is registered to this broadcast receives that update.

Using the push approach, it would mean that even if the app is killed, the push can still be triggered. 
It seems a bit of a waste.

But considering that there might slow connection, connection drops, etc., the websocket is also quite "vulnerable".

Also, what if 24 hours of a story expire, how do I make sure I always remove that story from the Stories list view and not keep displaying it ?
With a socket, we may lose connection. if we reconnect after we were to supposed to be notified that the Story time expired, we would still display that Story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the stories in some sort of database, together with their creation dates. A client can then periodically fetch for new stories. Based on the creation date, the client can calculate the age of the story and decide to show it or not.

If a story has been seen by the client, he can store that information in local storage so watched stories can be displayed as old stories.

Now for the cleanup part, there are two options. Either you write a program that runs on a server 24/7, that like a client, periodically fetches the stories from the database, checks their age and deletes those which are too old. The other approach would use the same concept, but all normal clients delete old stories from the database.

The second option would be very insecure though, because the age calculation could be manipulated on the client side, either by mistake or by an attacker.

Comment: thank you for the response.
1. your approach means that a client would have to use Polling, i.e - periodically check to see if there are any story updates. That's why I preferred the websocket approach for this, to avoid polling, and get updates in near-real-time.
2. regarding storing the dates in local db - these creation times would have to be converted by client to their device's time zone ? there might be a time-syncing challenge here, no?  and as you said - user can manipulate date (or a seasonal change in time zone can occur), and I didn't quite understand how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well, the creating client can already calculate the expiration date and save it together with timezone information, the viewing client can convert this to his local timezone without any problems. Regarding the live updates, you can still implement something like FCM or Sockets when the app is online to inform a client that he has to fetch from the DB

Comment: and what if the user changed his time, for example set it back a few hours , the timezone calculation would be irrelevant here I think

Comment: Even if it's only two users, one creator and one viewer, assuming that both check if stories are expired an delete them, both users would have to change their time by the same amount

Comment: @SteapStepper69 im also trying to implement same thing. In my case, i need to mark stories as seen if a user saw it, in web application aswell (both mobile and web app). So managing it in localstorage  will not work for me. Any thoughts regarding this usecase? Much appreciate.